# How to access parameters in the URL in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following routes in App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import MentorList from "./components/Mentor/MentorList";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Layout>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/mentors/:categoryId" exact element={<MentorList />} />
                </Routes>
            </Layout>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

In MentorList, I have the following:

```
 if (this.props.match && this.props.match.params.categoryId) {
            console.dir('test');
 }
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to access this.props.match.params.categoryId. I am wondering if this changed since I upgraded React. Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook from react-router-dom - useParams. [Read more here.](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams)
For example:

```
import React from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function MentorList() {
  const { categoryId } = useParams();
  return <p>{categoryId}</p>;
}

export default MentorList;
```

Comment: I don’t want to use functions. I want to use class components

Comment: @ChrisHansen, You should change version react-router to (Update) V4 & V5.
Maybe this will be work:
`"react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",`